# apparmor displays errors when evince is opened

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, evince, apparmor

I looked for similar problems but I could not find a question that helps so I'm asking it myself.
After running `apt-get purge python` on Xubuntu 14.04 and then realizing what I did, I had to manually install all packages that were deleted during that process.

Everything seems to run now, but when I open or scroll through a `*.pdf` file with evince, I get error logs like this:

```
Feb 16 10:13:34 enterprise kernel: [782525.032637] audit: type=1400 audit(1487236414.580:618): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer//sanitized_helper" pid=24903 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 16 10:13:42 enterprise kernel: [782532.988421] audit: type=1400 audit(1487236422.536:619): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/etc/xfce4/defaults.list" pid=25056 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=2126 ouid=0
Feb 16 10:13:42 enterprise kernel: [782533.090915] audit: type=1400 audit(1487236422.636:620): apparmor="DENIED" operation="link" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/user/2126/gvfs-metadata/.openRX20VY" pid=25056 comm="evince" requested_mask="l" denied_mask="l" fsuid=2126 ouid=2126 target="/run/user/2126/gvfs-metadata/root-8b3f7bff.log"
Feb 16 10:13:42 enterprise kernel: [782533.090931] audit: type=1400 audit(1487236422.636:621): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/user/2126/gvfs-metadata/root-8b3f7bff.log" pid=25056 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=2126 ouid=2126
Feb 16 10:14:23 enterprise kernel: [782574.114799] audit: type=1400 audit(1487236463.661:622): apparmor="DENIED" operation="link" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/user/2126/gvfs-metadata/.openLUS4VY" pid=25087 comm="pool" requested_mask="l" denied_mask="l" fsuid=2126 ouid=2126 target="/run/user/2126/gvfs-metadata/root-2badf972.log"
Feb 16 10:14:23 enterprise kernel: [782574.114812] audit: type=1400 audit(1487236463.661:623): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/run/user/2126/gvfs-metadata/root-2badf972.log" pid=25087 comm="pool" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=2126 ouid=2126
```

I have already tried adding my remote home folder to `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home`, which got rid of a lot more error messages, but those stated above still happen.

Answer (score 8):

**Install**

- `sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils apparmor-profiles`

When doing this below, only Allow changes for programs that you want to for the time being.

**Run**

1. `sudo aa-complain evince`
2. Open `evince` from your desktop as a regular user. Try running some
   searches in a file, opening closing and saving a file.
3. `sudo aa-logprof`  Allow/Deny changes as you wish.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you have a profile that allows you to
   do what you want to do.
5. `sudo aa-enforce evince`

***If that doesn't work***

**Run**

1. `sudo aa-cleanprof evince`
2. `sudo aa-genprof evince`

   Steps 3- 5. same as above.