# Ubuntu 16.10: segfault on evince-thumbnail

Tags: evince

**My Configuration:**

- A Lenovo T450s
- Ubuntu 16.10 64bit
- GNOME Shell 3.20.4

**My Problem:**

Sometimes suddenly and error pops up with 'Cancel' and 'Report problem` buttons. When I click on report problem this comes up:

[image]

Also, when I run `dmesg` I see this error line:

```
[ 1278.387019] evince-thumbnai[9012]: segfault at 50 ip 00007fd06dc0d940 sp 00007ffd97eecd98 error 4 in liblcms2.so.2.0.7[7fd06dbf9000+52000]
```

Any ideas how to fix or investigate the problem?

Comment: I'll start by submitting a bug against `liblcms2` on Ubuntu bugzilla.

Comment: I had the same issue but this answer solved it https://askubuntu.com/questions/883936/apparmor-displays-errors-when-evince-is-opened